# Extract props type from the whole ActionGroup in angular ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm creating actions with **createActionGroup** from **@ngrx/store** it looks like that:

```
export const myCustomActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Source name',
  events: {
    'My action': emptyProps(),
    'My action Succeed': props<{ parameter: SomeType}>(),
    'My action Failed': props<{ error: Error }>()
     ........
  }
});
```

based on that declaration I'd like to define a type for all the actions which are within the action group.

I know there is a possibility to create it like this:

```
export type MyActionSucceedType = ReturnType<typeof myCustomActions.myActionSucceed>;
```

but I am looking for a way that allows me to tackle the whole action group at once without a need to specify every single action explicitly